# Antlr4: How to pass current token's value to lexer's predicate?

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4, antlr4cs

Is there a way to provide a lexer's predicate with the current token's value? for instance, in my `lexer grammar FlowLexer`, I dynamically load tokens:

Before I parse, I load the tokens dynamically:

```
var lexer = new FlowLexer(new AntlrInputStream(flowContent)) {
    TokenExists = tokenValue => tokensDictionary.ContainsKey(tokenValue)
};
```

And then during parsing/lexing, the `TokenExists` predicate is called:

```
@lexer::members{
    public Func<string,bool> TokenExists = null;
}

/* ... stuff ... */

TOK : [-_.0-9a-zA-Z]+ 
    {!TokenExists(/*WHAT GOES HERE?*/);}? 
    -> mode(IN_TOKEN);

/* ... stuff ... */
```

But how do I pass the token value to the `TokenExists` predicate?

(This is an attempt to create context-aware lexer: I have several `mode`s, and in which one there are different rules).

Comment: why are you loading tokens dynamically?

Comment: @Zinov because I load my tokens from some external source (file/DB/...)

Comment: normally when you create the grammar, you should know all the tokens in advance, you are saying that you load them dynamically because you don't know the structure of the grammar?

Comment: @Zinov when the grammar is created/designed, it is possible to define say employees : 'peter' | 'paul' ....; At run time, when you want to validate an input phrase, there could be more employees and maybe 'peter' has left the company. You have defined the 'structure' of the grammar, but its 'content' may change at runtime. IMHO.

Comment: @peter.cyc I agree with you, but that should happen on the parser side with your AST while you are visiting the values of your node if you designed correctly your grammar, you shouldn't worried about a new employee. Your production should take care of it Employees -> name for example where name is a terminal production. Design the grammar well and you will have any values on your AST. Don't need to go at the Lexer level to address this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing token values in ANTLR4 predicates and actions is possible with a special syntax. For details see the [Actions and Attributes](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/actions.md#token-attributes) doc.

In general, you access a parsed token by using dollar sign and the token name, like

```
a: x = INT {$x.text == "0"}?;
```

or without a label (and only if the subrule exists only once in that parser rule):

```
a: INT {$INT.text == "0"}?;
```

ANTLR4 translates such pseudo code into target language code to allow accessing token properties (e.g. in C++ this becomes: `INT->getText() == "0"`).

In lexer rules, however, this [special access ist not possible](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexer-rule-actions) (ANTLR3 supported it, but not ANTLR4). Still, you can access a token's properties with native code (in fact it's not a token directly, since it doesn't exist yet, but values which will be used to create it from, once the lexer rule has finished). Though, this is often not portable to other target languages (which doesn't matter if you don't have more than a single parser target).

The code triggered in a lexer action (which includes predicates) is executed in the context of the lexer. This lexer keeps values from which the new token will be created, after the rule has ended. This allows to get the currently matched text:

```
TOK : [-_.0-9a-zA-Z]+ {!TokenExists(Text);}? -> mode(IN_TOKEN);
```

`Text` is a property of the [C# lexer](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/CSharp/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4.Runtime/Lexer.cs#L422).

Comment: If I change it to `{!TokenExists($TOK.text)}?`, I get `error AC0128: attribute references not allowed in lexer actions: $TOK.text`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that in ANTLR4 it is no longer allowed to use the attributes syntax. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! What I ended up doing is: `{!TokenExists(this)}?`, defining `TokenExists` as `public Func<FlowLexer,bool>` (then using the lexer object as `lexer.Text`). The problem is that it gives me char by char now, rather than as a whole. For instance instead of `print` token string, I get `p`, then `pr`, then `pri`, `prin` and `print`, and I can't distinguish between e.g. `print` and `print_line`. Is there a way around it?

Comment: This is by design, as you could also use the predicate to match only a specific length of the text.